# Floating Action Button in Android Click Listener

Tags: android, button, onclicklistener, floating-action-button

I have a simple floating image button for a pre lollipop version but when I am about to click on the button it fires with the second time. Do I need to make it larger?

```
fabImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "FAB CLICKED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            txtTitle.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            listView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            fabImageButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            lOUT.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }
    });
```

Does it matter that it is placed in Framelayout?

Comment: Just add padding to button

Comment: Its not working that way, I had extra parameters clickable and focusable in touch mode when I disabled them it was working